# Compiling QZ Tray with ant using self signed certificate

Tags: ant, qz-tray

I am trying to compile QZ Tray application with a self signed certificate using the ant command-line on a Mac. I have been following the [official guide](https://qz.io/wiki/compiling).

After checking out the code, I generated a certificate and key and used the following command:

`ant dmg -Dauthcert.use="cert.pem"`

also tried

`ant pkgbuild -Dauthcert.use="cert.pem"`

The build is successful without any errors and I get the installer from both commands above.

The installers work fine but the certificate I chose at compile time is missing when I install it. In the screenshot below, I expect `override.crt` to be present in resources. Running the installed application, QZ Tray site manager is empty. Manually adding the same certificate in the site manager solves the issue.

[image]

Following the successful build, the `out` folder contains a `dist` folder, which actually has `override.crt`. Running the jar file here works fine, QZ Tray site manager displays the certificate.

[image]

Any ideas why the certificate is not placed into the resources of the `dmg` installer?

Answer (score 2):

> Any ideas why the certificate is not placed into the resources of the dmg installer?

Because it's [a bug](https://github.com/qzind/tray/pull/899) with the `master` branch (sorry about that!).  It's since been patched so if you update your source code, you should be good. :)